# compare two symbol fields in kdb

Tags: kdb

I would like to compare two fields in KDB+.
so on the same row, one field contains another fields value

eg.

```
tab:([]col1:`abc`bcd`efd;col2:`$("/ee/abc/uuu");`$("/ee/abc/uuu");`$("/ee/efd/uuu"))
```

I would like to extract first and third rows because col1 values are in col3 on the same row

This is what I got so far:

```
 select from tab where any (string col1) like/: (string col2)
```

However it did not return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're wildcarding it on both sides (with "*"):

```
q)tab:([]col1:`abc`bcd`efd;col2:`$("/ee/abc/uuu";"/ee/abc/uuu";"/ee/efd/uuu"));
q)select from tab where col2 like'("*",'string[col1],'"*")
col1 col2
----------------
abc  /ee/abc/uuu
efd  /ee/efd/uuu
```